# How to check if the plane detected in WebXR's hit test results is vertical?

Tags: augmented-reality, hittest, webxr, web-ar

I am new to WebXR and trying to only allow the reticle to show up if the plane detected is vertical (like a wall).
I am following [this](https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr-samples/blob/main/hit-test.html) basic hit test example as a starting point. I don't see any parameter for vertical detection of the plane but in the demo, the reticle changes color when it's on a vertical wall.

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to only show the reticle if the plane is vertical?

I can see the position and rotation of the reticle being set here:

```
let pose = hitTestResults[0].getPose(xrRefSpace);
        reticle.visible = true;
        reticle.matrix = pose.transform.matrix;
```

Is there a way to access reticle orientation from this?

Demo: https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-samples/hit-test.html